# Unable to reboot or shutdown Linux Mint 17.1 on VMWare Player

Tags: linux-mint, reboot

I installed Linux Mint 17.1 on VMWare Player 7.1.0 but when I try to reboot the system, it says

```
ModemManager is shut down
```

and in the next line, it says

```
nm-dispatcher.action: Could not get the system bus. Make sure the message bus dameon is running! Message: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

Before this I renamed the file `org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service` to `thisfilebreaksmycomputer.service` from `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services` following this link Ubuntu 14.04 wont shutdown or reboot.

I tried with different commands like `sudo init 6`, `sudo reboot now`, `sudo shutdown now` but all the same.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Just force shutdown it from the VM options....

Comment: You mentioned a link. Which URL?

Comment: @A.B. not sure why the link is not showing inspite of me pasting on this page.

Comment: @ash.k29 I have been doing the force shut down but I think this is an issue with the Linux Mint. I tried it on Oracle Virtualbox and its the same.

Comment: I have the same issue actually. Have not found the solution yet. Can only shutdown by forcing vmware shutdown which is probably incorrect compared to the normal behavior.